# How to escape special charaters like % on ilike in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

How to escape the special characters such as %, & using ilike in rails

As i'm getting error when i enter special characters like %,& in search box , as my query was this book.where("book.name ilike ?", "%#{options[:book_name]}%")

How to escape the special characters using ilike?

Answer (score 1):

You can sanitize your query with [`sanitize_sql_like`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_like):

```
book.where("book.name ILIKE ?", "%#{sanitize_sql_like(options[:book_name])}%")
```

Comment: Sorry it didnt work,as it gave the error for using % alone in search box

Comment: Can you please post the full error message from the log file?

Comment: @JANARTHANANSHANMUGAM What exactly was in `options[:book_name]` when the error happened would also be useful.

Comment: @spickermann ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid query parameters: invalid %-encoding (%)):
this was the error i got

Comment: @muistooshort % was in options[:book_name]

Comment: `ActionController::BadRequest` is not a database level error message. It is a controller level error. That means nothing wrong with my answer on how to encode those characters in database queries. But instead, the issue is caused by how the form is sent to the controller. I suggest opening a new question for that and post how your form looks like and how you read the params in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with [`.gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-gsub) and a [regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Regexp.html).

```rb
options = { book_name: '%Hello & W%orld!' }
options[:book_name].gsub(/[%&]/, '')
#=> "Hello  World!"
```

The full solution is as follows:

```rb
book.where("book.name ILIKE ?", "%#{options[:book_name].sub(/[%&]/, '')}%")
```